# Saving and restoring selection while preserving presence of newline

Tags: pipe, echo

How can I use an environment variable to save and restore the
primary selection regardless of whether it ends in a newline or
not?

```
    p=$(xsel -p)
    echo "temporary value" | xsel -pi
    # ...
    echo "$p" | xsel -pi
```

will add a newline that wasn't there before.  Adding `-n` will
remove a newline that was there before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the workaround given [here](http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html). Add an extra character within the `$()`, and remove it afterwards.

```
p=$(xsel -p; echo x)
p="${p%?}"
```